# Automating an SQL task on a monthly basis

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, sql-server-agent

At the start of each month I have to give a team a copy of the live database which is held in a backup from 1am each morning (D:\Backup) - We then copy this database elsewhere onto a dev server and restore it from the share.

When January is completed at the end of the month we repeat the process for the Feb - this time we take a copy of what has been worked on during the month of Jan by the team and back that up into an archive. The February 1st database then goes live onto the dev server.

Is it possible to automate this process? Our techie left us recently and didn't document this process so I've managed to do it manually thus far but imagine it can be automated.

Comment: Hi, to answer this we need more information. Start with the basics: what database software?

Comment: Sorry Phil, should have made that clear. It is MSSQL on a server 2012 R2.

Comment: Using SQL studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

What you are telling is possible.

A pseudo code would look like this :

*[ Make sure to use database compression and have [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization) enabled.]*

- Check if it is first day of the month using `select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`
- if it is first day of month, backup the previous month database to archive as `db_name_datetime_Month_archive.bak`.
- backup the live PROD database and copy the file to DEV server and restore / overwrite the current database - use `WITH REPLACE` option when restoring.
- [Sync up users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances)
- Optionally since you are restoring database from PROD, you *may* have to sanitize it - remove PII or any sensitive information.
- send out email to the concerned teams (DEV in your case) saying the restore or refresh job has been completed.

For backup and restore you can use [PowerShell](https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools) (make sure you use backup and restore method) or [tsql](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/t-sql-restore-script-generator-3).

You can completely automate the above pseudo code using sql agent job.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to automate the process of backing up daily and automatically having the database restored onto the dev server from another location in the beginning of the month. I would look into BATCH files with SQL script exec statements. Then set up a windows task to run depending on the task (every 1st day of the month at 3am -- execute the restore command (this task would point to a batch file that would point to a .sql script and execute it etc).

For a clearer answer or actual examples, I would provide to the team here which database software you use as Phil stated, ORACLE uses SQL*PLUS which allows batch operations etc, SQL SERVER has its own etc...

Also if your goal is different then what I described, please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do and which parts you want to automate, I am sure there will be many helpful comments/answers to help get you pointed in the right direction.

Welcome to Stackexchange DBA! Get ready to learn alot using this knowledge center.

Comment: Hi Hector, this is fantastic. Thank you.

I will see what I can find on this stuff. The goal is to be able on the first of each month to automatically restore a live database to the development server so that some users can analyse the data over the past month. At the end of each month we will look to archive that DB off as a backup file to a volume and replace it with the new backup file from the 1st of that month. 

It is MS SQL and we use SQL studio to run the databases at the moment. I hope this helps, once again, thanks for your response!